# Android 2.2 Screen Lock Security

Tags: android, security, settings, lockscreen, android-2.2-froyo

Is there a way to find out if a user has the PIN lock or password lock screen security set?

I know that you can check `Settings.Secure.PATTERN_LOCK_ENABLED` to read if the pattern is set. Even a value to read that shows if ANY security is set would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS 2.2 you can find out if there is a minimum security policy in place using DevicePolicyManager [getPasswordQuality(null)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName%29).  It will return a PASSWORD_QUALITY_* constant indicating the minimum level of security in force, e.g.

```
PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED
PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING 
PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC        
PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC
PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC
PASSWORD_QUALITY_COMPLEX
```

Unfortunately I don't think that will tell you what quality of password protection the user currently has, i.e it only tells you if there happens to be a security *policy* in place (which won't be that common unless all your users have e-mail through an Exchange server which implements a security policy).

You can always call [setPasswordQuality](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) in your app to enforce a minimum device password though.

If you find an answer for this question that works on OS 2.1 I would be interested to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
mDevicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(component, 6);
```

then use:

```
mDevicePolicyManager.isActivePasswordSufficient())
```